# UIScrollView in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have added the UIScrollView into the COCOS2D game engine using 
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: tempScrollView];.
On that scroll view I have added a image view and a buttons. My problem is that the scroll view is scrolling vertically only. I want the UIScrollView to scroll horizontally only. Also I want the images to be rotate as well. I have tried the view transform property but its not working in my case.
Does any body know how to do this in cocos2d?

Comment: Hi all. I done this using cocoa xib.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontaly only ? try to change contentsize. e.g.:

```
ccp(5000,winsize.height)
```